# Using Accumulo as source and sink on Flink

Tags: apache-flink, accumulo

I would like to use Apache Accumulo to store events data and perform some computation on it with Apache Flink.

I know it's possible to do that with Apache Spark, read some records from Accumulo as RDD [Read from Accumulo from Spark shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38441884/read-from-accumulo-with-spark-shell?s=2%7C0.3302)

is it possible to use Accumulo as a source and sink on Apache Flink? What is the right way to do so?

Comment: Did you find any solution to your problem? I'd be very interested in how you solved the issue and how you integrated flink with accumulo.